# Is there anyway to do math on a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, math

I have two fields, one with the purchase date and one with the lifespan of an item. I am wondering if there is any way to determine if the current date is past the lifespan. So, pretty much if MySQL could test if current_date is > purchase_date + lifespan.

The purchase date is a date formated yyyy-mm-dd and lifespan is an integer of months. Is there any way to perform this calculation?

Comment: Give it a try and see what MySQL tells you.

Comment: Need to know what is stored in `lifespan` - days, weeks, years?  Then it's a matter of using [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: @OMGPonies, "lifespan is an integer of months"

Comment: It appears DATEDIFF only returns days...If you put INTERVAL field MONTHS in it it gives a Syntax error.

Comment: DATEDIFF is for days only, So I accomplished the task I needed by `code`DATE_ADD(a.date_acquired,INTERVAL  a.life_span  MONTH) < NOW()`code`  Thanks to the manual @feeela gave and to the rest of you for giving me ideas. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOW() > (purchase_date + INTERVAL lifespan MONTH)
```

But you might use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOW() > date_add(purchase_date, INTERVAL lifespan MONTH)
```

Or `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), purchase_date) / 30 < lifespan
```

Comment: This one, I believe, complains about a syntax error. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Travis, what's the syntax error? Have you tried the updated answer using `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: let me see if I can replicate it, but I think it was complaining about MONTHS and I tried MONTH too.

Comment: Opps, it's supposed to be [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) (with no S)

Comment: Yes it says "check manual...for the right syntax to use near MONTHS)" and if you use just MONTH it says "check manual...for the right syntax to use near )"

Comment: @Travis, you might need to use `CURRENT_DATE` in place of `NOW()`?

Comment: @Dirk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1389/discussion-between-travis-pessetto-and-dirk)

Answer (score 1):

How about using `DATEDIFF`?

Your query would be something along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), purchase_date) < lifespan
```

*Forgive me if my syntax is a little off, I don't have an SQL instance to test on right now*

Comment: I believe this one is missing the MONTHS interval and instead calculates for days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, using the [MySQL date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: I think it may be possible to use DateDiff in some way

Comment: Well, what should I say. The exact answer to the question may be found within the examples on the linked manual:
`DATE_ADD('2008-01-02', INTERVAL 31 DAY);` Which then may be compared like any other value in MySQL… Are you searching for an answer, or for pre-coded-copy-and-paste-please-do-my-work-snippets?

Comment: No, I just didn't know where to look in the Manual.  The most advanced QUERYs I have done are SELECT * FROM table WHERE colum='value...with LIKE.

Comment: @Travis Pessetto: the last comment was meant to @OMG Ponies

Comment: I do like this link to the manual, because it explains the exact syntax.  At first glance of dateDiff I thought it just returned days, now it is more clear it returns what I need.